# Create a map via folium with multiple points

Tags: python, folium

#### Problem

I wrote this code almost word by word, and get this error. 
The datasheet is approximately 1000 lines long if this is relevant.

How do I solve this issue?

#### Code

```
import folium
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
lat = df.Latitude
lon = df.Longitude
name = df.Docking

m = folium.Map(location=[20, 0], tiles="Stamen Terrain", zoom_start=9)

locations = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']]
locationlist = locations.values.tolist()

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    folium.Marker(lon[i], lat[i], popup=df.Docking[i]).add_to(m)
```

#### Error:

```
----> 2     folium.Marker(lon[i], lat[i], popup=df.Docking[i]).add_to(m)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'popup'
```

**EDIT:**
After the reply suggesting grouping the Lat and Long attributes, this error shows:

```
---> 16     folium.Marker([lon[i], lat[i]], popup=df.Docking[i]).add_to(m)

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

What probably happens is that longitude/latitude is expected as a tuple/list with 2 elements, then follows `popup`, but you're providing 2 elements *then* `popup` again

Example from the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html):

```
folium.Marker([45.3288, -121.6625], popup='<i>Mt. Hood Meadows</i>',
```

Standalone example:

```
def f(a,b,c=None):
    pass

f(12,34,b=12)
```

gives:

```
TypeError: f() got multiple values for argument 'b'
```

because `b` is passed as positional *and* keyword.

Grouping lat/long in a list fixes your code:

```
folium.Marker([lon[i], lat[i]], popup=df.Docking[i]).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the super slow reply, but this hasn't worked?
New error though shown as an edit